# PL SQL, Error(32,43): PLS-00201: identifier 'HR' must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, execute-immediate

I'm trying to execute the following procedure

```
EXECUTE StudentNames(12345, true)
```

I'm getting the below error;

> Error(32,43): PLS-00201: identifier 'HR' must be declared

It's linked to this part of the code:

```
 IF p_bool AND v_studid = 12345 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant select on '||HR||'.'||STUDNAME_12345||' to student_12345';
  END IF;
```

I'm looking to pass the student number and a boolean value to the procedure. 
If PASS -> the code will grant select privileges to student_12345 on table hr.studname_12345.

I can see the issue is linked to HR, just wondering how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE StudentNames
  (p_studnumber IN students.student_id%TYPE,
   p_bool IN BOOLEAN)
IS
  v_stud          students.student_id%TYPE := p_studnumber;
  v_studid        students.student_id%TYPE;
  v_firstname     students.firstname%TYPE;
  v_lastname      students.lastname%TYPE;

  e_no_test_returned    EXCEPTION;
  e_no_table            EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (e_no_table, -942);


  CURSOR  c_stud_cursor (p_studno NUMBER)IS
  SELECT  firstname, lastname 
  FROM    students  
  WHERE   student_id = p_studno;

BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'SELECT student_id 
  FROM students
  WHERE student_id = :v_stud'
  INTO v_studid
  USING v_stud;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_studid);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  ');

  IF p_bool AND v_studid = 12345 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant select on '||HR||'.'||STUDNAME_12345||' to student_12345';
  END IF;

  OPEN c_stud_cursor(v_studid);
  LOOP
    FETCH c_stud_cursor INTO v_firstname, v_lastname;
    EXIT WHEN c_stud_cursor%NOTFOUND;

------NAMES--------------------
      IF    v_studid = 12345 THEN        
            INSERT INTO studname_12345(first_name, last_name)
            VALUES ( v_firstname, v_lastname);
            COMMIT;


      ELSIF v_studid = 12346 THEN        
            INSERT INTO studname_12346(first_name, last_name)
            VALUES ( v_firstname, v_lastname);
            COMMIT;

      ELSIF v_studid IS NULL THEN
        RAISE e_no_test_returned;

    END IF;

  END LOOP;


  CLOSE c_stud_cursor;



EXCEPTION
--The value passed to the student_id parameter is not an integer. 
  WHEN INVALID_NUMBER THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The value passed to the student_id parameter is not an integer');

  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('More than one student with same id');

--The value passed to the student_id parameter does not exist in the student tables. 
--The value passed to the student_id parameter is null.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student ID does not exist in the student table');  

--There are no test results for the Student.  
  WHEN e_no_test_returned THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are no results for Student - '||v_stud);

  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Some other error occurred.');


END StudentNames;
/
```

CREATE STUDENT / ROLE / ADD ACCOUNT TO ROLE

```
CREATE USER student_12345
IDENTIFIED BY pw1234;

--Create a Student Role 12345
CREATE ROLE student1;

--Adding the account to the student role
GRANT student1
TO student_12345;


--Allow accounts access the database
GRANT create session 
TO student_12345;
```

CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE studname_12345
  (first_name   VARCHAR2(30),
   last_name    VARCHAR2(30)
   );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got no variable named `HR` in your code - that's what Oracle complains about.

What you probably want instead of this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant select on '||HR||'.'||STUDNAME_12345||' to student_12345';
```

is this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant select on HR.STUDNAME_12345 to student_12345';
```

Comment: Thank you Frank - running now.

Comment: @saggart You're welcome. If this fixed your problem, please consider marking my answer as accepted (by clicking the checkmark next to it).